# Toastr message for angular forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a angular form. So in the field I have set toastr messages for validation so that empty field doesn't gets submitted. It works fine and shows toastr message but when I enter two spaces and submit the form it still accepts and submits it. I want a toastr message showing the form field is empty when we enter two spaces or empty spaces and submit.Is there any way to sort it out?

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
  this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    customer_id: ['', Validators.required],
   
    
  })

}
   if (this.customerForm.value.customer===""){
    this.toastr.error('Add customer field' ,{timeOut: 1500});
    return false;
  }



       <td>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off" required>
</mat-form-field></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove whitespace from the start and end of your string before comparing it to the blank string.

```
if (this.customerForm.value.customer.trim() === ""){
    this.toastr.error('Add customer field', {timeOut: 1500});
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks it works. Can u help in a situation where the user can only enter upto 20 characters in  a form field in toastr? Anything above 20 characters shouldd show a toastr message

Comment: `this.customerForm.value.customer.trim().length > 20`